# Accessing files from users local machine from deployed server (i.e. my webApplication) in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, image-uploading, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am developing a web application where I want to get image from user.
So I wrote a `Servlet` to get file path from user. I'm passing file path as...

```
localhostApiBase/image?path=/home/userName/Pictures/25.jpg
```

I deployed my application on localhost and Its working fine. i.e. my application found the file and processed as intended. I'm reading image like this

```
File oFile = new File(path);    
BufferedImage oImage = ImageIO.read(oFile);
```

Then I deployed my application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and when I'm trying to hit the same `Servlet` with same path as....

```
serverApiBase/image?path=/home/userName/Pictures/25.jpg
```

then

```
File oFile = new File(path);
oFile.exists(); // returns false
BufferedImage oImage = ImageIO.read(oFile); // throws java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/userName/Pictures/25.jpg
```

After some efforts I came to know that it is trying to find file on server `(AWS Elastic Beanstalk)` not on my (user's) local machine. So it is throwing

```
       java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException .
```

Can anyone help me solve the issue. I want users to upload images from their machine, which I will use further....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the image from the user during run-time you have to create some upload logic. Here is a good explanation: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

If the image is static, i.e. part of the application use the aproach mentioned by Drux.

Answer (score 0):

Save the user uploaded file on the server storage like this,

```
        File targetFile = new File(filePath);
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        outStream.write(buffer);
        outStream.close();
```

and access the file like this,

```
        server_ip/image?path=filePath
```